# Establecer un fondo grandiente en xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xaml, fondo

Tengo una duda y es que si puedo establacer un fondo gradiente para un stacklayout o cualquier elemento en xamarin forms. Esto puedo hacerlo desde c# proyecto principal o tiene q ser x proyecto ya sea en .android o en .iOS

Como puedo hacerlo?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: tenes que hacer un custom render. Busca esa info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible hacerlo utilizando una librería llamada MagicGradients, aquí te adjunto un [tutorial](https://medium.com/@benetskyybogdan/gradient-background-for-your-xamarin-forms-app-6d7e46fba558)  de como utilizarla. Además de lo que se menciona en el tutorial, debo decirte que es importante utilizar la etiqueta ContentPresenter de esta manera:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PageWithGradient1">
        <Grid>
        <magic:GradientView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <magic:GradientView.GradientSource>
                    <magic:CssGradientSource>
                        <x:String>
                            <![CDATA[
                linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(26, 14, 114, 0.5) 0%, rgba(26, 14, 114, 0.5) 16.667%,rgba(21, 47, 104, 0.5) 16.667%, rgba(21, 47, 104, 0.5) 33.334%,rgba(16, 80, 93, 0.5) 33.334%, rgba(16, 80, 93, 0.5) 50.001%,rgba(10, 112, 83, 0.5) 50.001%, rgba(10, 112, 83, 0.5) 66.668%,rgba(5, 145, 72, 0.5) 66.668%, rgba(5, 145, 72, 0.5) 83.335%,rgba(0, 178, 62, 0.5) 83.335%, rgba(0, 178, 62, 0.5) 100.002%),linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(7, 214, 89) 0%, rgb(7, 214, 89) 16.667%,rgb(20, 192, 100) 16.667%, rgb(20, 192, 100) 33.334%,rgb(33, 170, 110) 33.334%, rgb(33, 170, 110) 50.001%,rgb(45, 147, 121) 50.001%, rgb(45, 147, 121) 66.668%,rgb(58, 125, 131) 66.668%, rgb(58, 125, 131) 83.335%,rgb(71, 103, 142) 83.335%, rgb(71, 103, 142) 100.002%)
            ]]>
                        </x:String>
                    </magic:CssGradientSource>
                </magic:GradientView.GradientSource>
            </magic:GradientView>
        <ContentPresenter /> <!--Esta etiqueta es para que se pueda ver el contenido de la actividad sobre el background-->
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Y además no te asustes por ese código CSS tan largo, en este [link](https://www.gradientmagic.com/collection/simplepatterns) puedes encontrar varios gradientes de ejemplo junto con su CSS.

Espero haber sido de ayuda. :)